# If my Sqlite class can take a string and insert a row or take a string and query a row why do I need a seperate getter setter class?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am having a hard time understanding the getter/setter class in a tutorial. It has me create a class that handles my database management. Within in it is db insertion that calls another class to handle the getting and setting. To me it looks like it hands the getter/setter the contact name and phone number and then asks what is the name and phone number....

The getter/setter class:

```
public class Contact {

//private variables
int _id;
String _name;
String _phone_number;

// Empty constructor
public Contact(){

}
// constructor
public Contact(int id, String name, String _phone_number){
    this._id = id;
    this._name = name;
    this._phone_number = _phone_number;
}

// constructor
public Contact(String name, String _phone_number){
    this._name = name;
    this._phone_number = _phone_number;
}
```

A method inside the db class

```
void addContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

usage: `db.addContact(new Contact("Ravi", "9100000000"));`

Could I instead forgo the getter/setter class and just pass the values to the addContact method?

Why are there two contact constructors with one missing the id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact object is there to encapsulate data related to one contact person. Just basic oo approach to modeling data. Makes it e.g. easier to pass contacts around. The constructor that does not take an id is for when you create a new contact that has not been persisted yet and hence does not have an id.  This id might be generated by the database.